# Displaying Video in React JS Modal Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, html5-video, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to display a video in REACT JS in modal full screen. I have the video as a local file in the project. I want to have the video as a thumbnail with a play button. Once someone clicks play, they would get the video to play as a modal popup in full screen.

I tried using the `react-modal-video` component but I can't figure out how to get it to work with a local file and it seems to use a button instead of a thumbnail for the video.

This is my code where I pass the `Vid` as the video prop to the component ( I can get it to easily render with ReactPlayer or a html video tag) but I am trying to do it using the modal popup I discuss above.

```
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="player-wrapper">
            <ModalVideo custom className="react-player" autoplay isOpen={isOpen} url={Vid} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
        </div>
)}
```

Comment: call setOpen(true) and see if it works.

Comment: that did not work